# Swift 3: Unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift3, unrecognized-selector, addtarget

I have a button in my view class attempting to add a selector function from a separate class as follows:

```
class ProfileView: UIView {
    createAccountButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ProfileViewController.createAccountClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
}

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    func createAccountClicked() {
        print("button press")
    }
}
```

I am getting a unrecognized selector error when I am trying to reference this method outside of `ProfileView`. However it works when I simply put `createAccountClicked()` into `ProfileView` and call:

`createAccountButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.createAccountClicked), for: .touchUpInside)`

instead. My question is - Is it possible to call a function from a separate class? Or would just having the function in the same class be the correct design pattern to follow?

Comment: With `addTarget` at place of `self` you need to pass the reference of `ProfileViewController`.

Comment: `ProfileViewController.self` works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue try changing the code like below:

```
class ProfileView: UIView {
    createAccountButton.addTarget(ProfileViewController, action: #selector(ProfileViewController.createAccountClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

Is it possible to call a function from a separate class? Or would just having the function in the same class be the correct design pattern to follow?

**Yes**, **you can call a function from outside by declaring a class function or an object of that class. Check the class function below**

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
 class func someTypeMethod() {
    //body
}
}
```